# Hadoop yarn/yarn NPM name conflict

Tags: linux, bash

I have yarn Node Package Manager wrapper installed:
https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/migrating-from-npm/

I can use both yarn and yarnpkg in my BASH shell to run the command for yarn NPM wrapper.

After I installed Hadoop with YARN (Yet Another Resource Manager). I am not able to use the Hadoop yarn command globally because it is taken by yarn NPM wrapper. How do I fix it so that `$yarn` runs Hadoop YARN?

I want to run `$yarn` from

```
/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.3/bin/yarn
```

Right now `which` prints for my yarn NPM wrapper.

```
$which yarn
/usr/bin/yarn
```

Answer (score 0):

The maintainers of yarn (the package manager) [have no intention of changing the name of their binary](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/673#issuecomment-254004512) even though hadoop's yarn has been around for years:

> We don't have any intentions of using the yarnpkg binary as the sole one. There's prior art here with Node.js using node instead of nodejs even though there's already a Debian package called node. See #673 for more information.

I think this is a pretty weak excuse as the "Amateur Packet Radio Node program" referenced is much less widely installed than hadoop.

In the issue referenced in that response, [the same maintainer says](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/673#issuecomment-254004512):

> Sorry but we have no intention of renaming this project. I've added a bin alias called yarnpkg in cefa9a3 that should be available in the next release if this is conflicting with existing binaries on your system.

Of course, adding an additional alias doesn't fix the fact that their `yarn` is still conflicting with hadoop's `yarn`.